# AWS API Gateway HTTP Request Interceptor

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm not able to find any documentation about intercepting all HTTP requests passing through AWS API Gateway.

I'm trying to propose a Logging service for the backend APIs deployed on AWS API Gateway. The idea is all the HTTP requests will go through the API Gateway. If I'm able to intercept the request going through API Gateway, I can hook the logging service code.

The reason for this approach is, the logging code will be independent of the actual service code and service code won't have to be updated to include logging of request / response.

Any solutions for this?

Comment: I had a similar requirement. I built a flask app and used zappa to deploy to APIG/lambda. This allowed me to intercept all requests and migrate to new services.

Comment: @al76 Interesting! Is there any place where I can see through the implementation details or a blog you referred while doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put CloudFront in front of your API Gateway and then use Lambda@Edge Viewer Request to intercept all requests; we do this for logging for certain functions and it works flawlessly.

This is a good tutorial on how to setup API Gateway with CloudFront
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudfront-distribution/

Comment: This seems like a good solution. Note the step where the tutorial says to use a regional (not edge-optimized) API deployment.  This improves latency when you deploy your own CloudFront distribution in front of API Gateway -- otherwise you are looping every request into and out of the AWS Edge Network twice instead of just once.

Comment: We have few APIs on Lambda and few running on EC2 inside a VPC. With Lambda@Edge Amazon VPCs cannot be used; so I'm afraid this might not work for me!

Comment: You did not mention this in your question; your question is very specific about API Gateway, and intercepting the request to API gateway, nothing about intercepting requests to API’s running elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Claudia-bot-builder's [intercept](https://github.com/claudiajs/claudia-api-builder/blob/master/docs/intercepting.md) method will help you to intercept the API gateway requests. You can trigger an event for requests hitting to the API gateway.

```
          `api.intercept(function (event) { ... });`
```